# Selenium Webdriver sometimes starts chrome but no page is loaded

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I have created a web crawler using selenium for a research project that requires simulated user interaction. I am currently running 8 individual instances (processes) of the webdriver with a custom Chromium Binary.

The main issue now is that web driver will sometimes (non deterministically) start  chromium and then freeze on the data; page that is always opened up. i.e. it never navigates to the specific URL I want. You can see a screenshot of what happens.

This happens after about ~100 urls are crawled. I have not been able to find a solution on StackOverflow :(. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D.

[Screenshot of Chromium Instance frozen on the data; page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0sqh.png)

EDIT: Also, I don't know if this is effecting it but my web driver emulates a mobile device. As such, I manually set the size of the Chromium window to the size of a mobile device screen. I sometimes receive the error describedbelow.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined
JavaScript stack:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined
    at updateWindow (chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/background.js:66:17)
    at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:23)
    at executeAsyncScript (<anonymous>:321:26)
    at apply.height (<anonymous>:337:29)
    at callFunction (<anonymous>:229:33)
    at apply.height (<anonymous>:239:23)
    at <anonymous>:240:3
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:878:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:811:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:667:21)
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2594.0)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 893 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'momalad-virtual-machine', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_72-internal'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=true, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ftGDsH}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=true, version=49.0.2594.0, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: dbc9347c26adc9507436d38f3c2bbd58
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.setSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:891)
    at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.setupPosition(TestChromeDriver.java:160)
    at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.setupDriver(TestChromeDriver.java:155)
    at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.crawl(TestChromeDriver.java:256)
    at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.main(TestChromeDriver.java:113)
    ... 5 more
```

EDIT 2: For clarity I am adding my web driver setup code as requested:

```
/**
 * Sets the browser in mobile mode (Nexus 5)
 * Sets the timeout for pages that don't load to 15 seconds
 */
public void initBrowser(){

      // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
      // IF it can't be found, it will needed to be moved to the local directory of this java project
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/mnt/crawl/mobmalad/ChromeAdCrawler/Dependencies/chromedriver");

      setupDriver();
}

private void setupDriver(){
    ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
    opts.setBinary("/mnt/crawl/mobmalad/ChromeAdCrawler/Dependencies/Release/chrome"); 
    opts.addArguments("--no-sandbox");


    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");

    opts.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opts);


    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);    

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    setupPosition();
}

private void setupPosition(){
    //Determine the desired height and width of the window and store it as a dimension
    int desiredHeight = 728;
    int desiredWidth = 414;   //Half the screen width
    Dimension desiredSize = new Dimension(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);

    //Set the size of the window to the dimension determined above
    driver.manage().window().setSize(desiredSize);

    if(crawlerID<(crawlers/2)){
        driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point((int) (crawlerID*desiredWidth*.6), 0));
    }else{
        driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point((int) ((crawlerID-(crawlers/2))*desiredWidth*.6), (int) (desiredHeight)));
    }
}
```

Comment: This really doesn't sound like a very scalable solution. Selenium Grid was designed to avoid having to create large number (e.g. > 5) of real browser instances. What's your CPU like?

Comment: @AndrewRegan I only have one server to work on and it seems to be able to handle these 8 concurrent crawlers. Selenium Grid requires >1 server instances right?

Comment: @DieterMeemken I have looked at other stack overflow answers that suggest upgrading selenium/chrome as well as changing proxy settings. I have updated my selenium and have always had the most recent Chromium and I don't understand why this would be a proxy problem.

Comment: Your error says `Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined`. Are you doing this? We need to see your code.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I think the error stems from me trying to explicitly set the size of the Chromium window. I removed this setsize call and it stopped producing that exception but does not resolve the original problem. I will edit the post to add my web driver setup code :D.

Comment: I really think you're going to have to narrow this problem down yourself as there are too many variables, e.g.: only certain urls? Is mobileEmulation a factor? Does it happen with < 8 instances? Try without the resizing? Without the timeouts?

Comment: @AndrewRegan Yes to all

Comment: Please edit your post with any more info you have ^^ so we can help diagnose.